# htaccess how to hide url (ex. from www.test.com/test.html to www.test.com)

Tags: html, .htaccess

My question is same as the title. I have already tried a lot of your answers and they were just for php sites.

Comment: What do you mean `hide`? Are you talking about `url-rewrites`?

Comment: This question won't be here long but look into mod_rewrite.

Comment: [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$ test.html [L]
```